# Ошибка в Drupal

Tags: drupal

Ощибка

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 39 of 47 bytes in variable_initialize() (line 1189 of /var/www/local.martin.academy/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дана ошибка была детально разобрана здесь

[unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset)

В этой ситуации ошибка возникает потому что создавалась запись в таблице с кодировкой `utf8mb4`. И в какой то момент кодировку сменили на `utf8`. Как известно в этих кодировках некоторые символы будут занимать разное количество байт

Вот согласно кодировке `utf8mb4` значение занимало 39 байт, и это записано в сериализованой строке

s:39:"martin.glogger@lifeentrepreneur.academy";

но когда кодировку сменили на `utf8` эта же строка стала занимать 47 байт, и в момент когда попытаться сделать `unserialize` строки возникнет ошибка

Для того что бы исправить ситуацию

```
drush @none dl utf8mb4_convert-7.x
drush cache-clear drush
drush utf8mb4-convert-databases
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2754539

https://www.drupal.org/node/529866

увидеть неверные переменные можно следующим способом

```
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {variable}')->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $variable){

  $variables[$variable->name] = @unserialize($variable->value);

  if ($variables[$variable->name] === FALSE) {
   print $variable->name . '=' . $variable->value . '============================================';

   // fix strings

   if(FALSE !== preg_match('#^s:[0-9]*:"((.|\n)*)("|&quot);#', $variable->value, $math)){

    variable_set($variable->name, serialize($math[1]));
   }

  }
}
```

а потом просто заново задать  им значение, в этот момент оно создастся с верной кодировкой. Это нужно сделать для каждой переменной которая будет получена выше

```
variable_set('name', 'value');
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/upgrade_fails_mysql57-2665362-2.patch